# NIC throughput monitoring by process

Tags: windows-xp, network-monitoring

Does anyone know of a decent tool for XP to monitor the throughput of a NIC by process? Something similar to the Resource Monitor baked into Windows 7 would be perfect. I’ve considered [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org) but don’t need to analyse down to the packet level, just need a good real-time bytes per second tool.

Answer (score 1):

Perfmon can do this for you in a gross way, but it might just be enough for what you need. Try the "Process" object, choosing the process you want to monitor, and graphing / recording the "IO Other Bytes / sec" counter. The "Explain" text for this counter in Windows XP is:

> The rate at which the process is
>   issuing bytes to I/O operations that
>   do not involve data such as control
>   operations. This counter counts all
>   I/O activity generated by the process
>   to include file, network and device
>   I/Os.

If the process is doing Microsoft "file and print sharing" access via SMB, then you'll want the "IO Read Bytes / sec" and "IO Write Bytes / sec", though if the process is also doing IO to the local disk then those IO counts will be mixed in, too.